# numbers problem in code

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I'm having some problem with my code. 
It works fine when I compile it until I get to the point when the numbers divide. I'm not getting numbers with decimal, only zero. As you can see, I already changed the last variables to double but it didn't have any meaningful result.

What must I do to change this?

```
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        System.out.println("enter two numbers: ");
        arr[0] = sc.nextInt();
        arr[1] = sc.nextInt();

        int summa = arr[0]+arr[1];

        System.out.println("What's "+arr[0]+" + "+arr[1]+" ?");
        int vad = sc.nextInt();

        if (summa == vad)
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong - The right answer is "+summa);


        int summa2 = arr[0]-arr[1];
        System.out.println("What's "+arr[0]+" - "+arr[1]+" ?");
        int vad2 = sc.nextInt();

        if (summa2 == vad2)
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong - The right answer is: "+summa2);


        int summa3 = arr[0]*arr[1];
        System.out.println("What's "+arr[0]+" * "+arr[1]+" ?");
        int vad3 = sc.nextInt();

        if (summa3 == vad3)
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong - The right answer is "+summa3);


        double summa4 = arr[0]/arr[1];
        System.out.println("What's "+arr[0]+" / "+arr[1]+" ?");
        double vad4 = sc.nextInt();

        if (summa4 == vad4)
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong - The right answer is "+summa4);



}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1** you are reading ***int*** it should be ***double***  .
**2** You need to cast to ***double*** check code below

```
    double summa4 = ((double)arr[0])/arr[1];
    System.out.println("What's "+arr[0]+" / "+arr[1]+" ?");
    double vad4 = sc.nextDouble();

    if (summa4 == vad4)
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    else
        System.out.println("Wrong - The right answer is "+summa4);
```

Comment: and 3) compare doubles using a range like `(summa4 <= vad4 + 0.01 && summa4 >= vad4 - 0.01)` testing doubles for equality is a problem because of floating point artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

Although *summa4* variable is of type double, but it's calculation is done in integer division. Therefore, the result would not have any decimal place.

For example, 5/2 = 2 and not 2.5 if both 5 and 2 are integers or values stored in int type variable.

change:

```
double summa4 = arr[0]/arr[1];
```

to

```
double summa4 = 1.0*arr[0]/arr[1];
```